# Stripe issues: requires_capture

Tags: stripe

Most transactions are fine, but some cards are starting to come up with some kind of deadlock between Stripe and Civi. They leave an unresolved $1 charge in Stripe and fail on the Civi side entirely, with the following error:

[image]

I'm running Civi 5.22.0, with Wordpress 5.3.2–en_CA and Stripe extension 6.3.2 
I am not, to my knowledge running any other processing related extensions, but here is a screenshot of my extension page for the curious.

[image]

Comment: Keith, are you running any other extensions related to finance, contributions, fees, etc.?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. World events overtook me. There are no other extensions related to financial transactions. There have been no further instances of this problem since Mar 13, but there have only been a handful of transactions anyway and the problem seemed to occur about 10% of the time.

Comment: Getting the same message for every transaction, at the moment.

Much worse, $200 even is getting added to every transaction! Fortunately, these are all tests, at the moment.